# Does XMPP require a dialback?

Tags: xmpp

I've been doing it as follows :

```
Step 1. <Stream>
Step 2. <Auth> (PLAIN)
Step 3. <Session>
Stuck here.
```

This tutorial does not mention dialback: http://ceit.uq.edu.au/content/how-xmpp-works-step-step

However, under 8.3. Protocol of the documentation, it says to use a dialback: http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html

Right now, this is the full response I get from my server:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='1027203257' from='mysite.com' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
<stream:features><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='yy7di5kE0syuCXOQTXNBTclpJWo='/><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/></stream:features>
<success xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'/>
<stream:error><xml-not-well-formed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/></stream:error>
</stream:stream>
```

I've seen in some peoples code, after step 2, they run `<stream>` again, but in others they don't. Is this needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Server** Dialback is uses for s2s (server-to-server) connections. You don't need it for c2s (client-to-server) connections.